# Prevent list box automatically selecting first item when binding changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a setup like this:

ViewModel snippet:

```
private ObservableCollection<Field> _Fields;
public ObservableCollection<Field> Fields
{
    get
    {
        return _Fields;
    }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(ref _Fields, value, "Fields");
    }
}

private Field _SelectedField;
public Field SelectedField
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedField;
    }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(ref _SelectedField, value, "SelectedField");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FieldList" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedField}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I update the field collection quite frequently, like this:

```
List<Field> myFieldList = myDataSource.GetFields();
Fields = new ObservableCollection<Field>(myFieldList);
```

When I do this, the list box automatically defaults to selecting the first item. I would like it to not select anything by default (e.g. `SelectedIndex = -1` or `SelectedValue = null`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but no luck. I have a `ListBox` and an `ItemsSource` binding. It doesn't select the first item to me. Are you sure it's not in your code?

Comment: I didn't think it mattered, but maybe it does ... I edited my question because I am also binding the SelectedValue of the list box to a property on my VM. **No code sets this value**, I am positive this is a default WPF behavior of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it but could not reproduce it. 
If you already have SelectedField in your VM try to set it tu null just after you update Fields.

You could also try to use an Action/Trigger to set the SelectedIndex to -1 like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="FieldList" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedField}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding Fields}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=FieldList}" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But actually it is not the best way to reset the selection.

Comment: That was it, I just had to set `SelectedField` to `null` whenever I refreshed the data. It must have something to do with the fact that the selected value was bound, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

After binding or loading the list, set

```
listbox1.SelectedIndex=-1;
```